Snowflake dynamic masking for column based on another column value
In Snowflake, I am wanting to know if one can dynamically mask a column value (say Column_A) based on the value of another column (say Column_B) in the same row being evaluated. So, the result would be Column_A is masked in some rows but unmasked in others, dependent on the value of the corresponding Column_B. Maybe this is not even possible?
Here is a hacked together masking policy statement to give you an idea of my thinking.  The problem is what to put in place of ???
create or replace masking policy PII_SENSITIVE as
(val string) return string
case when exits ( select 1 from Tbl_Customer where Column_B = ???)
then val -- unmasked
else repeat (‘\*’, length(val)) -- masked
end;

.
Been exploring dynamic masking, but also row level security in the Snowflake docs

data masking is meant to be used for role-based scenarios, rather than data-related.  Based on your question, why wouldn't you simply use a secure view with a case statement over the table, and then only grant view permissions on the view (and not the table)?

Hi - you can pass multiple columns into your masking policy as parameters and use them in your masking policy logic. This is explained, with examples, in the documentation. If this is not what you are trying to do, please could you provide more details in your question?

To address Mike’s suggestion of views, this is what we do today. The views are on any tables containing PII and they filter out whole rows based on some level of customer classification level. Two problems with this: 1) Leads to a proliferation of RBAC roles and 2) We would rather see all the rows but dynamically obfuscate the PII columns based on the classification level and the role of the user.

To Nick’s suggestion, I have been looking at this in the docs, but they are not super clear. I understand that the first argument is the column to mask and you can have other input arguments. What I don’t follow is how these argument values get supplied at runtime. They have this “email_visibility” example in the docs (see below). Where does the “visibility” argument value come from – is it supposed to be the name of another column on the same table as the email column? If it is, then this might just work.

create masking policy email_visibility as
(email varchar, visibility string) returns varchar ->
case
when current_role() = 'ADMIN' then email
when visibility = 'Public' then email
else 'MASKED'
end;

Yes, it’s another column in the table and will pick up the value for the current row from that column

Fabulous NIck... I will have a crack at that. Much appreciated

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
